checking etcd cluster works correctly
when i run the command below, I got the error and my exit code is 1.Can anyone tell my why i got this error and how to fix it?
Thanks
kubectl exec etcd-master -- etcdctl member list
{"level":"warn","ts":"2024-12-28T12:28:32.978637Z","logger":"etcd-client","caller":"v3@v3.5.15/retry_interceptor.go:63","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"etcd-endpoints://0xc000370000/127.0.0.1:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest balancer error: last connection error: connection error: desc = \"error reading server preface: EOF\""}
Error: context deadline exceeded
command terminated with exit code 1

also my etcd logs is like this.my firewall is off and selinux is also permissive.My os is rocky linux 9.3.
{"level":"warn","ts":"2024-12-28T12:42:13.018454Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:170","msg":"rejected connection on client endpoint","remote-addr":"127.0.0.1:52198","server-name":"","error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"}
{"level":"warn","ts":"2024-12-28T12:42:14.022364Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:170","msg":"rejected connection on client endpoint","remote-addr":"127.0.0.1:52214","server-name":"","error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"}
{"level":"warn","ts":"2024-12-28T12:42:15.330400Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:170","msg":"rejected connection on client endpoint","remote-addr":"127.0.0.1:52222","server-name":"","error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"}
{"level":"warn","ts":"2024-12-28T12:44:21.880909Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:170","msg":"rejected connection on client endpoint","remote-addr":"192.168.56.101:42196","server-name":"","error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"}
{"level":"warn","ts":"2024-12-28T12:44:22.883450Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:170","msg":"rejected connection on client endpoint","remote-addr":"192.168.56.101:42210","server-name":"","error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"}
{"level":"warn","ts":"2024-12-28T12:44:24.622810Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:170","msg":"rejected connection on client endpoint","remote-addr":"192.168.56.101:42220","server-name":"","error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"}
{"level":"warn","ts":"2024-12-28T12:44:26.821834Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:170","msg":"rejected connection on client endpoint","remote-addr":"192.168.56.101:42222","server-name":"","error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2024-12-28T12:46:45.062979Z","caller":"mvcc/index.go:214","msg":"compact tree index","revision":228269}
{"level":"info","ts":"2024-12-28T12:46:45.079467Z","caller":"mvcc/kvstore_compaction.go:69","msg":"finished scheduled compaction","compact-revision":228269,"took":"10.947531ms","hash":4017906930,"current-db-size-bytes":3809280,"current-db-size":"3.8 MB","current-db-size-in-use-bytes":1859584,"current-db-size-in-use":"1.9 MB"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2024-12-28T12:46:45.079800Z","caller":"mvcc/hash.go:137","msg":"storing new hash","hash":4017906930,"revision":228269,"compact-revision":227809}


The error was because of not knowing about the cert,cacert and key file.
After passing these files, the connection and the output was ok.
